# OPTIMIZING LEFT JOIN in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT h.*
FROM  h
 LEFT JOIN  au ON au.ID = h.Key AND au.RaID = 40190 AND h.EntityType = 'Detail'
 LEFT JOIN  ip ON ip.ID = h.Key AND ip.RaID = 40190 AND h.EntityType = 'itempart'
WHERE 
coalesce(au.id,ip.id) is not null
```

Anyone have a good idea how to optimize this? h is HUGE history log table.

Comment: Check the query plan in SQL Management Studio. It will suggest indexes if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about using a union on your allowed types then you can use an inner join:

```
SELECT h.*
FROM  h
    INNER JOIN (
                SELECT ID, 'Detail' AS EntityType FROM au WHERE (RaID = 40190)
                UNION ALL
                SELECT ID, 'itempart' AS EntityType FROM ip WHERE (RaID = 40190)
            ) AS filt
            ON h.Key = filt.ID
            AND h.EntityType = filt.EntityType
```

also make sure you have indexes on your filtered/joined columns. And as always when looking for performance issues check the query plan as n8wrl suggests above.

Comment: clustered or not clustered index?  Where does the execution plan suggest an index?   I see one particular step in the actual execution plan that it is 92%, when i hover over it, what do i look for?

Comment: you can only have one clustered index on a table. The execution plan gives you a visual representation as to how the query will be executed. By looking where the heaviest parts are and then looking at what those parts are doing you can then determine where to start optimizing. If there is an obvious missing index it will suggest it at the top of the execution plan. You can also try running the query through the Database Engine Tuning Advisor (seperate app that comes with sql).

Comment: 1 other question: how does this query handle left and inner differently?  This accomodates left?

Comment: with the two left joins and you marking it as having to have at least one of those (with the coalesce not being null) then it is the same as just saying it has to be in at least one of the two tables. So inner joining on the two tables combined is doing the same thing.